# Get a list of the functions contained in an R package without downloading package

Tags: r, cran

Is there a simple way of getting a list of the functions contained in a package without downloading it?

I have explored extracting the 'topics' of a package's reference manual (from CRAN).

This gets all the functions in a package (as a character vector), but unfortunately also gets unwanted items, since the list of topics in a package's reference manual can also contain items that are not simply functions.

Is there a better way of cleanly obtaining a list of functions for a package?

Comment: It would only get you to the exported functions/objects but you could look at the NAMESPACE file provided. For example https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/NAMESPACE

Comment: @Dason thanks, that's exactly what I was after

Comment: @Dason I tried this approach. But packages that use `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")` or similar [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/A3/NAMESPACE) to export their functions won't have all individual functions listed in their NAMESPACE file (and may not have any). Any other ideas?

Comment: Does this help? Or is this again a problem of showing functions which are "not simply functions"? https://cloud.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/ggplot2/R/

Comment: @HectorHaffenden From inspecting ggplot2 (as you provide) and dplyr, it looks like it may work, however after trying a few other packages I can see it doesn't cater to all CRAN packages. I would prefer to pull the info directly from CRAN if possible so as to reduce the risk of an incomplete list of packages (I need to be able to replicate for all packages on CRAN)

Comment: Yh seems to only work for some more mainstream packages, a potential solution, could you use reference manuals, but do some creative web scraping, so you get all the functions listed after the usage section? For example, for <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/A3/A3.pdf>, I see 3 different types, `A3-package`, `a3` and `plot.A3`. The 1st just being a description, second being a function and third a method. So, webscrape and look for the usage section, get the function after that and add it to the list. For the functions, it will add, for the methods it will add a duplicate of...

Comment: base functions, and you can remove these using `unique`. So... not exactly a simple way, but combining this to only apply to functions that use `exportPattern` in their namespace, could make it a bit more efficient... let me know if this is simple enough.... lol ;)